# Can SharePoint Migration Assessment Tool (SMAT) scan a SharePoint Server 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-server, migration

Can SharePoint Migration Assessment Tool (SMAT) scan a SharePoint Server 2016?

If not, is there an equivalent tool for it?

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/overview-of-the-sharepoint-migration-assessment-tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can in SharePoint 2016, even though the tool says 2010 and 2013. I've done this on our SharePoint 2016 environment and it provided good results.

Comment: thanks for sharing. We ended up rewriting most of the custom code with spfx in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking for details report SharePoint 2016 like web application details, site collection details, list details etc..

All this kind of individual report can be generated using the ShareGate or Metalogix tool, I think it is not doable through the SMAT.

Note:

- Whichever tool you use you can not generate all reports within a single step, you have to generate each type of report separately.

Comment: Basically I looking at these functionalities: 1 - Assessment: Run a scan looking for issues that have been known to cause issues for customers migrating into SharePoint Online. 2 - Identity Mapping: allows you to generate a report of all the user and group identities that have access to your SharePoint environment and attempts to map those identities to Azure AD user and group identities.

Comment: Ohh, I think you need go with powershell script for this.